# Update object in foreach loop

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, foreach

I am using EF4/LINQ for the first time and have run into an issue.  I am looping thru the results of a LINQ query using a foreach loop as follows:

```
   private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) 
   {
      CallOutcomeSubmission los = new CallOutcomeSubmission();      
      client = connectToService();

      try
      {
         using (var context = new CallOutcomeContext())
         {
            // List of available actions
            private static string ACTION_CALL_ATTEMPT = "Call Attempt";
            DateTime oneDayAgo = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24);
            var query = from co in context.T_MMCallOutcome
                        join ca in context.T_Call on co.CallID equals ca.CallID
                        join lv in context.T_LeadVendorEmailHeader on co.LeadVendorEmailID equals lv.LeadVendorEmailID
                        where co.EnteredOn > oneDayAgo && co.MMLeadActionID == null
                        select new
                        {
                            co.CallOutcomeID,
                            co.CallID,
                            co.LeadVendorEmailID,
                            MMLeadID = lv.email_text,
                            ca.OutcomeID,
                            lv.FranchiseNumber,
                            co.MMLeadActionID,
                            co.LeadAction
                        };

            // if any results found for query
            if (query.Any())
            {
               foreach (var call in query.ToList())
               {
                  // if the franchise exists 
                  if (client.FranchiseExists(int.Parse(call.FranchiseNumber)))
                  {
                     switch (call.OutcomeID)
                     {
                        case 39:    // Not Answered
                           call.LeadAction = ACTION_CALL_ATTEMPT;  
                           break;
                        case 43:    // Remove from Call List
                           break;
                        default:    // If the OutcomeID is not identified in the case statement
                           break;
                     }  // switch

                  }
                  else
                  {
                     los.eventLog.WriteEntry("CallOutcomeSubmission.OnTimedEvent: No franchise found with franchise ID " + call.FranchiseNumber);
                  }

                  // Save any changes currently on context
                  context.SaveChanges();

               }  // foreach

            }

            // if no results found from query write system log stating such
            else 
            {
               los.eventLog.WriteEntry("CallOutcomeSubmission.OnTimedEvent: No new entries found");
            }
         }  // using

         client.Close();
      }
      catch (System.TimeoutException exception)
      {
         los.eventLog.WriteEntry("CallOutcomeSubmission.OnTimedEvent:" + exception.ToString());
                    client.Abort();
      }
      catch (System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException exception)
      {
         los.eventLog.WriteEntry("CallOutcomeSubmission.OnTimedEvent:" + exception.ToString());
                    client.Abort();
      }
    }
```

When I try to do the assignment:

```
call.LeadAction = ACTION_CALL_ATTEMPT;
```

I get a build error of

```
Property or indexer 'AnonymousType#2.LeadAction' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

I can't seem to find anything on this specific error doing a Google search and am not sure what I am doing wrong.  Is it because the original query contains a join?

How can I do the assignment of call.LeadAction within the foreach loop?

I would also like to know if there are design issue withe way I have written the query or performed any of the operations since this is my first foray into EF/LINQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new anonymous type - with the Linq joins and then trying to set that value. What you're really wanting to do, is update the call's `LeadAction` correct?

How would EF know to translate your new query back to an entity so it can go back to the database?  It would have to go through alot of hoops, and it's not capable of that.

What you could do, is retrieve the `Call` from your database and set the `LeadAction` that way - I'm using Find, assuming that `CallID` is your PK:

```
                  case 39:    // Not Answered
                       var thisCall = context.T_Call.Find(call.CallID)
                       thisCall.LeadAction = ACTION_CALL_ATTEMPT;                              
                       break;
```

Comment: Excellent, that worked.  Just to be clear, the reason that EF cannot translate the assignment back to an entity is because of the join in the query?  If the original query ('query' in my code example) did not contain any joins then the assignment in the foreach loop would work?

Comment: Correct - and if you were to return the actual entity type (Call in this case).

Comment: It isn't really the join that causes the problem, but the fact that you are returning a new object. You would get the same issue without the join if you returned a new object such as new { co.CallID ,  co.LeadAction} . Also you may be able to avoid the issue by returning the full entity inside your new  select new
                        { co, 
                            MMLeadID = lv.email_text,
                            ca.OutcomeID,
                            ...                          
                          
                        };

Comment: @sgmoore How would I specify the full entity in the select?  I know when doing a query WITHOUT a join I can just do 'select co' (using my original query).  How do I include 'ca' & 'lv' in the 'select'?